# Unable to change value at edit time with codeIgniter validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Here i have a list of categories and user can add a new category as well as edit them.

Now at the edit time i'm using server-side validation by codeigniter for reduce redundancies . but the issue is the, whenever i edit an existing category then it can't update it because it compare with their original value, that is wrong. i trying to many time but unable to fix this issue.

**Here is my code**

```
public function category_upd()
{
    extract($_POST);
    $userId = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $original_value = $this->db->query("SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE user_id=".$userId." and  cat_name ='".$_POST['cat_name']."'") ;

    $original_value  = $original_value->result_array();
    $original_value = $original_value[0]['cat_name'];

    $original_value2 = $this->db->query("SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE user_id=".$userId." and  cat_name ='".$_POST['cat_name']."'") ;

    $original_value2  = $original_value2->result_array();

    $original_value2 = $original_value2[0]['cat_name'];

    if(ucwords($_POST['cat_name']) != $original_value) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('cat_failed','Category must be unique.');
        $is_unique =  '|is_unique[category.cat_name]';
    } else if(ucwords($original_value2 == "")){

        echo "go";
        exit;

        $this->session->set_flashdata('cat_failed','Category must be unique.');
        $is_unique =  '|is_unique[category.cat_name]';
    } else {
        $is_unique =  '';
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name','Category','trim|required'.$is_unique);
    if($this->form_validation->run() ) {
```

**A snap with error**

[image]

I need your kind efforts. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a form\_validation rule from a library in CodeIgniter (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813779/set-a-form-validation-rule-from-a-library-in-codeigniter-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set validation Rules like this and you need to pass category id value

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'cat_name', 'required|trim|edit_unique[category.category_name.' . $_POST['category_id'].'.'.$_POST['user_id']. ']', array('edit_unique' => 'Category must be unique.'));
```

> And developed one function edit_unique on Form_validation.php like this
>   Filepath system/libraries/Form_validation.php

```
 public function edit_unique($str, $field)
    {

        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field,$id, $field2);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str, 'id !=' => $id,'user_id'=>$field2))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;

    }
```

Comment: one more query to you, please

Comment: suppose, we've two users and their have different id(s). and if one have category named "student" of one user. then the second user cant be edit any category with "student" name..! why ?

user id(s) are always different na

Comment: ok i got it your question  you can also pass user_id, category id on edit_unique function

Comment: ok,, two user are here ( dev,sonu ) and their id(s) are (5,6) . now dev have 
 created a category named  "student". now sonu tries to create or edit category name with "student" thenit can't. 

categories are must be unique but only for single user, not every user. 

Now, got it?

Comment: pass user_id value and check on where clause user_id=$user_id

Comment: can you update your answer, would be nice for us. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148286/discussion-between-reena-mori-and-devendra-singh).

Comment: please check my updated answer.. and let me know if any problem

Comment: yup, i'll be their?

Comment: issue Fixed.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check category name is alredy in database.

```
 $newcategoryName=$this->input->post('category');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('category', array('cat_name' => $newcategoryName,'user_id' => $userId));
    $val=$query->result_array();
    $original_value = $val[0]['cat_name'];
            if($newcategoryName != $original_value) {
               $is_unique =  '|is_unique[users.EMAIL]';
            } else {
               $is_unique =  '';
            }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'Category', 'required|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Comment: have you understand my question or not ?

Comment: I have edited the code. post your new category name to a variable and check weather new category name in your table

Comment: but we also need to check with user id that is requested to change their category name.

Comment: we've two users and their have different id(s). and if one have category named "student" of one user. then the second user cant be edit any category with "student" name..!

Comment: check category name and userId in `get_where` query